# Grouping Query with Has Many Relations in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a `has_many, through:` relationship between Projets and Categories using a Categorization model. A Projet `belongs_to` a Client.

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projets
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projets, through: :categorizations
end

class Categorization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :projet
end

class Projet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
end
```

For a specific category I'd like to list all the projets, grouped by the client. e.g.

(for category_id = 3)

Client A
Projet 1
Projet 2

Client B
Projet 3

Client C
Projet 4

So far I can get this working, but only by using two queries (one of which is very inefficient (n+1 problem).

This is the code

```
def listing
  @projets_clients = Projet
    .select("client_id")
    .includes(:client)
    .joins(:categorizations)
    .where(categorizations: { category: @category })
    .group("client_id")

  @clients = []
  @projets_clients.each do |p|
    @clients << Client.includes(:projets).find(p.client_id)
  end
end
```

If anyone can suggest a better approach I'd love to learn how to optimise this as I haven't been able to find a better way myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this. For complex queries I sometimes find it easier to write and execute straight SQL. However for your case, depending on data size, you could just eager load the data and turn it into a hash.

Note: When I was testing this code I used `projects` instead of `projets`.

```
@category = Category.includes(projects: [:client]).find(2)
@projects_by_client = @category.projects.group_by(&:client_id)

# In your view
<%- @projects_by_client.each do |client_id, projects| %>
  <%= projects.first.client.name %>
  <%- projects.each do |project| %>
    <%= project.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

A more fleshed out solution might use full sql with a query object and presenter object. I spun up a quick project using the below code and the output is what you are looking for.

```
# app/controllers/clients_controller.rb
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    result = ClientQuery.call(params[:id])
    @presenter = ClientPresenter.new(result)
  end
end

# app/services/client_query.rb
class ClientQuery
  class << self
    def call(client_id)
      sql_query(client_id)
    end

    protected

    def sql_query(client_id)
      ActiveRecord::Base.
        connection.
        execute(
          sanitized_sql_statement(client_id)
        )
    end

    def sanitized_sql_statement(client_id)
      ActiveRecord::Base.send(
        :sanitize_sql_array,
        [
          sql_statement,
          client_id
        ]
      )
    end

    def sql_statement
      <<-SQL
        SELECT
          c.id AS client_id,
          c.name AS client_name,
          p.name AS project_name
        FROM
          clients c
        INNER JOIN
          projects p ON p.client_id = c.id
        INNER JOIN
          categorizations cz ON cz.project_id = p.id
        INNER JOIN
          categories ct ON ct.id = cz.category_id
        WHERE
          ct.id = ?;
      SQL
    end
  end
end

# app/presenters/client_presenter.rb
class ClientPresenter
  attr_reader :clients

  def initialize(data)
    @clients = {}
    process_sql_result(data)
  end

  private

  def process_sql_result(data)
    data.each do |row|
      client_id = row['client_id']

      @clients[client_id] ||= { client_name: row['client_name'] }
      @clients[client_id][:projects] ||= []
      @clients[client_id][:projects] << row['project_name']
    end
  end
end


# app/views/show.html.erb
<%- @presenter.clients.each do |client_id, client_presenter| %>
  <h1><%= client_presenter[:client_name] %></h1>
  <ul>
  <%- client_presenter[:projects].each do |project_name| %>
    <li><%= project_name %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

This is of course just one of many ways you could go about getting your data in a single query and presenting it.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the details answer! The SQL approach is really interesting. Sorry for the confusion with 'projets' (its in French).

The code in your first example has a small error though, but thanks to your generous help (how to nest includes!) I think I worked out what it was:

@projects_by_client = @category.projects.group_by(&:client_id)
(need to add the .projects too — and the '@clients =' line is extraneous too I think)

Maybe it would be useful for others to update this & then I can mark it as the right answer?

Now it works perfectly, thank you so much!